# Is it ever OK to use a question mark after a period?

Tags: question-marks, periods

I know you can abbreviate the United States as U.S., US, or USA.

If you elect to use U.S., can you use a question mark after this version?

For example: Do you like to travel to the U.S.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when using an abbreviation that ends with a period, it is acceptable to follow this with another (different) punctuation mark, as in your example:

> Do you like to travel to the U.S.?

Reference: Jack Lynch's *[Guide to Grammar and Style](http://andromeda.rutgers.edu/~jlynch/Writing/p.html#periods)*: